# Breakpoints not hit when debugging Rust with gdb in Visual Studio Code

Tags: gdb, rust, visual-studio-code

I started learning Rust, and I want to set up debugging in Visual Studio Code, but can't get breakpoints working. I use the Native Debug & RustyCode extensions for VS Code.

Here is my launch file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug",
            "type": "gdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "target": "target/debug/test",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I run this configuration, breakpoints do not get hit. I see in the debug console that the debugger started and the app ran fine, but there is a warning message "No Symbols loaded":

```
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Running executable
[New Thread 32168.0x81e0]
[New Thread 32168.0x3360]
[New Thread 32168.0x61b8]
[New Thread 32168.0x8040]
The program "+ + * - /" calculates the value 1
[Thread 32168.0x61b8 exited with code 0]
[Thread 32168.0x3360 exited with code 0]
[Thread 32168.0x8040 exited with code 0]
[Inferior 1 (process 32168) exited normally]
```

Here is the [source of the app I am using](https://github.com/thecoderok/rust-playground). How can I make breakpoints work?

Comment: What is gdb version you are using ?

Comment: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9.1

Comment: I had a similar issue and I found that if I have hyphens in my project name (E.g. "abc-def"), then the code will run, but the breakpoints won't hit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same problem until I realized I was using an `msvc` build of `rustc`.

**GDB is only supposed to work with `gnu` builds**, so if you use rustup, the solution is as simple as `rustup default stable` (or beta/nightly). GNU is default, for msvc you would need to do `stable-msvc`).

If you don't want to use rustup you should just re-install a gnu build of Rust manually.

Edit: As noted in a comment below, don't forget to re-build!

Comment: And if you're wondering why it still doesn't work like I was, don't forget to re-build!

Comment: On Windows msvc is the default for rustup
https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs#working-with-rust-on-windows

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems with breakpoints and found that adding this line to the settings.json fixed it:

```
{
    "debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere": true
}
```

I am also using Microsoft's C/C++ Debugger plugin, not the native one. It still works for GDB.

Answer (score 0):

As it was said before - `gdb` debugger doesn't work well with `msvc` build of rustc.
Rustup defaults to `msvc` build on Windows right now.

To switch your default rustc build to `gnu` you have to run this command:

```
rustup default stable-gnu
```